# Group cohomology of a compact connected orientable genus $g$ surface without boundary and removing two open disks

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

> Let $V_g$ be a compact connected orientable genus $g$ surface without boundary. Further, let $X$ be $V_2$ with two disjoint open disks removed, and let $X'$ be $X$ with three distinct points identified. Calculate $H^*(X,\mathbb Z)$ and $H^∗(X',\mathbb Z)$.

I was thinking of drawing a $4g$-hedron and after gluing it we will get $1$ vertex and $2g$ edges with identified vertices and diagonal edges, which will be a wedge product of $2g + 1$ circles. I don't know whether my process is right. Please help.

Comment: (You probably mean cohomology ring instead of group cohomology.) Hint: $X$ deformation retracts onto a 1-dimensional complex which has a very simple cohomology ring. $X'$ is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of well-known spaces.

Comment: @Kevin.S Yes, my bad, it's cohomology ring. But can you kindly elaborate the hint?

Comment: Drawing definitely helps. Let's say you identify three distinct points (call them $p,q,r$), then consider the space $Y$ formed by attaching arcs that join $p, q$ and $q, r$ respectively. $Y$ deformation retracts onto $X'$ by contracting these arcs, and $Y$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1\vee S^1\vee V_2$.

Comment: @Kevin.S I was thinking, if we take $g = 2$, then what would happen?